# Paypal form not prepoulating

Tags: php, paypal

My paypal form wont prepopulate the address info. I'm sure I'm including all fields necessary. It only fills in name last name phone and mail. Here is my form code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="NC3DJAZLDWU34">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Membership/Contribution">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Leave a message for UMVA">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.umvaonline.org/index.htm">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.umvaonline.org/umvajoin.html">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to UMVA Homepage">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=<?php echo $fname ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value=<?php echo $_POST['last_name']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value=<?php echo $_POST['address1']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value=<?php echo $address2 ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="city" value=<?php echo $_POST['city']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value=<?php echo $_POST['email']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="state" value=<?php echo $_POST['state']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value=<?php echo $_POST['zip']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_a" value=<?php echo $phonearray[0] ?>>
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value=<?php echo $phonearray[1]?>>
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_c" value=<?php echo $phonearray[2]?>>

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=<?php echo $amount ?>>

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><br /><br /><a  href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Cancel</a>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are looking good until you get down to

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=<?php echo $fname ?>>
```

There you need to add quotations around the value, like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed the quotes...for some reason its still not working.

Comment: You have a combination of $_POST values and non $_POST values. I'm assuming this is posting from another page? What does the code on that page look like? You might want to just try doing a print_r on the $_POST array to see if things are actually getting passed correctly to the form above.

Comment: It looks like they're not getting the values, yet some of them appear in the paypal screen

Comment: I changed them all to variables but still not working. I'll see if those variables contain the value just before the form

Comment: when I echo the variables out they do print